# Remove "None" radio-button from custom option of product

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1.9, custom-options, product-view

I have added custom option in product as radion button. Its showing fine on frontend but above my custom option label its showing by default 'None' radio button. Is there a way to remove this.

Please check the screenshot for this -

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the option to be required.

or

rewrite method `getValuesHtml` in class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Select`, you need to comment these lines (from line 101):

```
    if (!$_option->getIsRequire()) {
             $selectHtml .= '<li><input type="radio" id="options_' . $_option->getId() . '" class="'
            . $class . ' product-custom-option" name="options[' . $_option->getId() . ']"'
            . ($this->getSkipJsReloadPrice() ? '' : ' onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()"')
            . ' value="" checked="checked" /><span class="label"><label for="options_'
            . $_option->getId() . '">' . $this->__('None') . '</label></span></li>';
    }
```

Comment: No, thats not the solution ... i have more than one custom options, its not mendatory to select every option

Comment: But if is is not mandatory imagine that customer selects `New type +$5.00` and after he wants to uncheck it. It is not possible if there is no `None` option

Comment: yes, thats not possible but still i am looking for any solution to remove this :)

Comment: okay, I give up :) I've added one more solution to the answer

Comment: i will approve answer for your effort and i will suggest my client to make options to be required. Thanks !

Comment: @TBIInfotech, you are welcome!